# ADC code for PIC

Tags: pic

I want to write a program in C that takes the input of the potentiometer in the pickit. The program should rotate the 4 LED in the pickit board left or right depending on the direction that the potentiometer has been rotated. if the arrow of the potentiometer points to the right the LED's should start to rotate to the right. Also the speed of rotation of the LED's should depend on how far from the center the arrow on the potentiometer points. Moreover, I would like to use the pushbutton on the board as a pause switch. So when the pushbutton is pressed the LED's should stop at their current position even when the potentiometer is rotating. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: I really dont know where to start with this one I am educating myself about ADC a little bit right now. If you can give me something to start with or point me in the right direction it will be appreciated.

Comment: I would highly recommend reading the datasheet for the particular PIC chip on your dev board. They generally include sample code for setting up the various hardware functions such as the ADC.

Comment: Once you've figured out how to read from the ADC and read/write digital pins, at a conceptual level you're basically doing the following: In a loop, 1) Read from ADC. 2) Subtract ADC value from some fixed offset representing the midpoint of the pot (this will probably be near 512 for a 10bit ADC). 3) This value is now your shift-speed, and its sign tells you direction (positive right, negative left). 4) Check if pause button pressed. 5) If not, shift LED lights in direction (remember the ``<<`` and ``>>`` operators. They make this easy).